# When I do submit formset in Django why do it returns extra 5 fields in formset?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I do submit formset in Django it returns extra 5 fields in formset. Suppose the initial queryset has 3 dictionary values. But when I do submit the formset its returns an extra 5 dictionary. Why?

My form.py:

```
class SbTitleForm(forms.Form):
    sb_title = forms.CharField(required=False)
    sb_permission = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

SbTitleFormSet = formset_factory(SbTitleForm, extra=0)
```

My view.py:

```
def menuuser(request):
    sbtitle = SbTitle.objects.all().values()
    sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(initial=sbtitle)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)
        if sbtitle_form.is_valid():
            print(sbtitle_form.cleaned_data)
            
    context = {
        'sbtitle_form':sbtitle_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'admins/user_role/user_permission.html', context)
```

My HTML:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %} 
{% load static %} 
{% block content %}
<div class="card">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ sbtitle_form.management_form }}
    {{ sbitleelement_form.management_form }}
    <div id="DataTables_Table_2_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
        <div class="datatable-scroll">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover datatable-highlight dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_2" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_2_info">
                <thead>
                    <tr role="row" class="bg-teal-400">
                        <th class="sorting text-center h5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Job Title: activate to sort column ascending">Sidebar Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for field in sbtitle_form %}
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="sorting_1 text-center"><h4>{{ field.sb_title.value }} {{ field.sb_permission }}<p class="text-danger">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</p></h4></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

when I try to **print(sbtitle_form.cleaned_data)** its return extra 5 field values like as **`[{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': True}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}, {'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}]`**. But I have only 3 initial values like as **`[{'id': 1, 'sb_title': 'Employ', 'user_role_id': None}, {'id': 2, 'sb_title': 'Today', 'user_role_id': None}, {'id': 3, 'sb_title': 'nextday', 'user_role_id': None}]`**. please help me to solve the

Comment: Are you using the `django.forms.modelformset_factory` or a different factory function?

Comment: I use django.forms.formset_factory

Answer (score 0):

If I use multiple formsets in one view, I need to use prefix for the forms as explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view In short

Like as:

```
sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(initial=sbtitle,  prefix='Title')
```